# How can I get mysql BLOB through GraphQL?

Tags: mysql, graphql

I need to download some file stored in MySQL DB as BLOB type.

Currently I'm trying to get it as string but GraphQL don't want to return this file.

Here is GraphQL schema:

```
type CV {
    ...
    title: String!
    file: String!       # Here is BLOB cell
}
```

Here is Screenshot from Mysql table named cv:

[image]

There is a way to store files in DB and download it through GraphQL? (At this time I found only way is to store it on Apache)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean "GraphQL don't want to return this file". Are you seeing an error? Are you getting `null` for that particular field, or some other part of the response?

Comment: Using GraphiQL I'm calling Query which should return file from blob cell in DB, there is empty space without any answer from server.

Comment: How are you fetching this data from your database? What ORM or library are you using?

Comment: Requests are handled with Zend Framework 3.0 on Apache.